# Creating multiple graphs from single data table

Tags: charts, google-sheets, pivot-table

I am trying to create a Google Spreadsheet for my sales for my business, that is happening on several different online portals e.g. Amazon, eBay, My Website, etc.

This is what I created:
[image]

But if I create this way then I do not get any graphs, which I really do need.

Though I tried other ways too, in which I had the portals in row 1 and dates in Column A, but in that case, I can have only one parameter, either No of Sales or Total Sales (rupees)

[image]

And the graph for this comes out nicely:

[image]

However, in this case, I would have to create separate sheet to record the Sales in Amount.

Is there a way to work this situation out, where I can create one table, and have graphs showing me the data as required as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good application for [Pivot Tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272898). Starting with your source data, you can either create pivot tables from the GUI (Data > Pivot Tables...) or by a formula using the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) function.

For example, this formula will create a table with portals in separate columns:

```
=QUERY(A:D,"SELECT B,SUM(C) WHERE A != '' GROUP BY B PIVOT A")
```

Note: A chart of this data requires that all cells be filled with numbers, so it's necessary that your source data includes zero values for portal/days with no sales, as shown in this sample data:

```
   A           B          C             D
Portal      Date     No of Sales   Total Sales
Amazon      June 18      33           45.62
Flipkart    June 18       2            2.64
Biocarve    June 18       3            4.32
Ebay        June 18       0            0.00
Amazon      June 19      22           37.01
Ebay        June 19       2            3.52
Flipkart    June 19       0            0.00
Biocarve    June 19       0            0.00
Biocarve    June 20       5            6.47
Flipkart    June 20       1            1.45
Amazon      June 20       8           10.69
Ebay        June 20       0            0.00
```

The pivot table output is:

```
Date       Amazon   Biocarve   Ebay   Flipkart
6/18/2016    33        3        0        2
6/19/2016    22        0        2        0
6/20/2016     8        5        0        1
```

And the chart:

[image: screenshot]

Likewise, this formula:

```
=query(A:D,"select B,SUM(D) WHERE A != '' GROUP BY B PIVOT A")
```

...tabulates the total sales, with this result:

```
Date       Amazon   Biocarve   Ebay   Flipkart
6/18/2016   45.62     4.32     0.00     2.64
6/19/2016   37.01     0.00     3.52     0.00
6/20/2016   10.69     6.47     0.00     1.45
```

You can also get all the summary data into one table, and produce a chart from that. (You need to customize your chart series to use left & right axes.)

The query:

```
=query(A:D,"select B,SUM(C),SUM(D) WHERE A != '' GROUP BY B PIVOT A")
```

The resulting table:

[image: screenshot]

And an example chart from that table:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Chart customization includes a checkbox to "plot null values", which might remove the need to include 0 data in the source data.